# como dar update no id

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, id

alguem pode me ajudar em atualizar o ID nesse código?

```
public function Editar_Cliente(){
            $dados = $this->DadosClientes;
            $id = $dados['id'];
            $nome = $dados['nome'];
            $cpf = $dados['cpf'];
            $email = $dados['email'];
            $endereco = $dados['endereco'];
            $numero = $dados['numero'];
            $bairro = $dados['bairro'];
            $cidade = $dados['cidade'];
            $estado = $dados['estado'];
            $telefone_celular = $dados['telefone_celular'];
            $telefone_fixo = $dados['telefone_fixo'];

            $dados_r = $this->Exec_SQL("UPDATE `clientes` SET `nome`='$nome',`cpf`='$cpf',`email`='$email',`endereco`='$endereco',`numero`='$numero',`bairro`='$bairro',`cidade`='$cidade',`estado`='$estado',`cep`='$cep',`telefone_celular`='$telefone_celular',`telefone_fixo`='$telefone_fixo' WHERE id = '$id'");
            if($dados_r){
                return $dados = array(
                    'codigo' => 0,
                    'mensagem' => 'Cliente editado',
                    'dados_enviados' => $dados, 
                );
            }else{
                return $dados = array(
                    'codigo' => 1,
                    'mensagem' => 'Erro ao editar o cliente',
                    'dados_enviados' => $dados, 
                    'erro' => $this->conexao->error,
                );
            }
```

eu só queria fazer isso:

```
UPDATE `clientes` SET `id` = '875' WHERE `clientes`.`id` = 874;
```

no caso, o id muda, coloquei 875 e 874 como exemplos.

já tentei e não foi:

```
$dados_r = $this->Exec_SQL("UPDATE `clientes` SET **`id`='$id'**,`nome`='$nome',`cpf`='$cpf',`email`='$email',`endereco`='$endereco',`numero`='$numero',`bairro`='$bairro',`cidade`='$cidade',`estado`='$estado',`cep`='$cep',`telefone_celular`='$telefone_celular',`telefone_fixo`='$telefone_fixo' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Comment: Por acaso o campo `id` de sua tabela é uma Primary Key? Um campo Primary Key não deve ter seu valor alterado.

Answer (score -2):

Tente isso:

```
$servidor = "local"; //DIGITE SEU SERVIDOR
$usuario = "user"; //DIGITE SEU USUÁRIO
$senha = "pass"; //DIGITE SUA SENHA
$dbname = "nome_tabela"; //DIGITE SUA TABELA
    
//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
    
if(!$conn){
    die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE clientes SET id='$id',nome='$nome',cpf='$cpf',email='$email',endereco='$endereco',numero='$numero',bairro='$bairro',cidade='$cidade',estado='$estado',cep='$cep',telefone_celular='$telefone_celular',telefone_fixo='$telefone_fixo' WHERE id = '$id'"
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Answer (score -2):

Opa Brother

Entendo que o que quer fazer não seria adequado ao processo de garantir integridade.

Pode ser que a id seja auto incremento e não permita a mudança.

Pode ser que o tipo está como string e não como número.

Mais na real o comando de atualização seria esse mesmo:

UPDATE `clientes` SET `id` = 875 WHERE `id` = 874;

Acredito que seja mais relacionado a estrutura do banco em não permitir.